# Entity Framework - Mapping Foreign Key to Business Key instead of Primary Key

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have two tables with a parent/child relationship, for example:

```
public class Business
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } //pk
        public int ABN { get; set; } //Business Key
        public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    }

public class Contract
    {
       public int Id { get; set; } //PK
       public virtual Business Business { get; set; }
       public int ABN { get; set; } //FK
    }
```

I'd like to map the relationship from child to parent on the business key, NOT the primary key. I thought the following in FluentAPI may do the trick, but I can't work out how to map to the BK instead of PK.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.Business)
                .WithMany(f => f.Contracts)
                .HasForeignKey(l => l.ABN)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation, the way to do this is with the HasPrincipalKey() feature. For example:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasRequired(l => l.Business)
                .WithMany(f => f.Contracts)
                .HasForeignKey(l => l.ABN)
                .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.ABN)
```

Disappointingly however, this is only available in EntityFramework Core not EntityFramework 6.2.

Comment: Yeah, support for alternate keys was introduced in EF Core. EF 6 can only use PK references.